# Unable to start the zookeeper server

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am running kafka on amazon EC2 and ubuntu. For starters I'm trying to run the zookeeper server and create a test topic. The ultimate aim is to integrate spark with kafka for sentiment analysis.

When I try to start the zookeeper server I get the following warning and the process doesn't seem to end i.e I don't see a shell prompt after i type this command: 
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties

WARN Either no config or no quorum defined in config, running  in standalone mode (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain)

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats a warning not an error .. your zookeeper should be running and you should be able to connect to it .. just open another tarminal and run (from ZK home)

```
    bin/zkCli.sh -server 127.0.0.1:2181
```

Answer (score 0):

optional commands to check server status:

```
echo ruok | nc 127.0.0.1 2181
echo mntr | nc 127.0.0.1 2181
echo srvr | nc 127.0.0.1 2181
```